# Clone SelectQuery doesn't seem to work

Tags: 7, views, database

I want to change the sorting of a view with something very specific which needs 2 subqueries.

So far, I tried to do something like this:

```
$sorted = false;

function mymodule_query_alter(&$query) {
  global $sorted;

  $view = $query->getMetaData('view');
  if( !$sorted && $view->name == 'my_view' ) {
    $sorted = true;

    $subquery_1 = clone $query;
    $subquery_2 = clone $query;

    // Apply sorting stuff...

    $query = $subquery_1->union($subquery_2);
}
```

Then I just realized that this desn't even work (while my view is working):

```
$subquery = clone $query;
$query = $subquery;
dpm($query->__toString());
dpm($query->arguments());
```

It doesn't return any result, but everything seems ok in the dpm dump.

Have I done something wrong? Or maybe should I handle this problem in another way?

EDIT:

I need to get a list of nodes sorted this way:

1. Sticky nodes | order by date.
2. Nodes in one of the taxonomy-term selected in user profile | order by date.
3. Other nodes | order by date.

I've already a working SQL request (actually 3 with `UNION`), but I need to make it work with Drupal.

Comment: I would expect it to be more useful to use **views** `hook_views_query_alter` rather **core's** `hook_alter`. Have you tried this?

Comment: with reference to other ways to handle the problem, we might need some additional detail about what you are trying to accomplish. Might it be possible to use Relationships, for example?

Comment: @autopoietic I tried with the views hook, but it uses a `views_plugin_query` object which doesn't provide `UNION` instead of a `SelectQuery`. I'll edit my answer for further details.

Comment: "It doesn't return any result, but everything seems ok in the dpm dump." - looks like views creates the query you told it to, but not the one you want... What happens if you run it directly in DB, using commandline client, or interface like phpmyadmin?

Comment: @Mołot As I said, the SQL query seems to work. Without alteration query alteration: `$query` returns results, and doesn't if I just `clone` it before.

Comment: So it can be replicated in four steps? Create query, execute, clone it, execute, see the difference? If so, please provide this test :) Because now you are overriding original after cloning, and that may cause some errors given that clone on this particular object does not copy db connection, for example.

Answer (score 1):

So, I was working on a test for @Mołot to reproduce the `clone` bug, and I couldn't with a fresh view.

I tracked down the difference :

- With the filter `Published or admin`: the cloned query didn't return anything.
- No problem with the simple `Published` filter.

Don't ask me why.

As @autopoietic said, working with core `query_alter_hook` wasn't a good idea. I switched to views hook, and got the `SelectQuery` object :

```
function mymodule_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
  $query = &$view->build_info['query'];
}
```

Then I was able to do my sorting.

Comment: I would guess the `clone` didn't work because further in the views processing the `node access checks` are added for `published` and `user role check`. These checks are adding during processing via meta data to the Query object.